# Define Specific route in Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a use case where we have a route[ route could be zig-zag or straight line].Route has several bus-stops.And we already know the lats long of the every bus-stops.

Now i want to identify the position of the user between the bus-stops who is travelling in the same route. I know the current lat-long position of the user.

The problem is, if the route is in form of zigzag then  i could not identified the correct position of the user between the bus-stops based on lat-long of the bus stop.

Could anyone help me know?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.
Best Regards,
Vaibhav

Comment: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html